# Finding vector components along a unit vector without calculating size?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

How do you find out the components of a vector in the direction of a unit vector without calculating the size of the original vector in the process?

If V is the vector and U is the unit vector then to get the component of V (say Vc) in direction of U , the straight forward way seems to be following:

S = Sqrt(V.x^2 + V.y^2 + V.z^2)

Vc = (S * U.x)i + (S * U.y)j + (S * U.z)k

In this approach you need to find the size of V which involves finding a square root which is computationally expensive and time consuming.

Are there any simpler methods to get Vc from V with less computation?

Comment: Look up orthogonal projection.

Comment: Use scalar multiplication of the vector with the unit vector.

Comment: @Moti you lose the sign of you do that

Comment: multiply with U

Comment: @Moti yeah but that gives you the vector in that vector's reference frame and not in original vector's . So compoonent of say -2,1,-1 in direction of -1,0,0 will come out to be 2,0,0 and not -2,0,0

Comment: @amd orthogonal projection needs to calculate sqrt

Comment: Multiply by Ux only

Comment: No, it does not. You don’t need to know the length of $V$ explicitly to compute its projection, and even if $U$ isn’t a unit vector, its length appears in denominators twice, you you really need only the _square_ of its length.

Comment: @amd How do you calculate length of a vector without using a sqrt?

Comment: $v\cdot v = \|v\|^2$.

Comment: By the way, what you’ve computed in your question isn’t the component of $v$ in the direction of $u$, but a vector in the direction of $u$ that has the same length as $v$. That doesn’t seem like what you were after.